# What are the controls present in "Dev Express controls" for Silverlight, for implementing good-looking menus?

Tags: silverlight, devexpress

What are the controls present in "Dev Express controls" for Silverlight, that help or are used in implementing a simple good looking menu?

And what would the best choice, and the most flexible control? Flexible in the sense of:

- mouse over
- key down
- key up
- mouse left and right clicks
- keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DXBars Suite for Silverlight](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Silverlight/Bars/) to create a menu in a silverlight application.

Comment: Just FYI, screenshots are missing on that page: http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Silverlight/Bars/Gallery.xml

Comment: Thank you, I will record a bug to the WebSite team :)